# how to create subdomain for every user who log in to my website dynamically in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, cakephp-2.0

how to create subdomain for every user who log in to my website dynamically in aws. Like if I have a domain example.com, and if a user talk2gourab log in, then the url shows example.talk2gourab.com

Comment: Please update the question with the steps you tried so far.

Comment: You won't ever be able to get it to show as "example.talk2gourab.com", but you could do "talk2gourab.example.com".

Comment: Hi Greg, Could you please let me know the process.---thanks, Gourab

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like MultiTenant CakePHP Plugin - Use this plugin to easily build SaaS-enabled web applications

https://github.com/pronique/multitenant

where you create Subdomain per Tenant